# Is there a way to use the style=authoryear and get the numerical citation?

Tags: bibliographies, biber, bibliographystyle

Is there a way to use the style=authoryear and get the numerical citation? I have,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
    b5paper,             % h=250mm, w=176mm
    inner=20mm,          % Inner margin
    outer=40mm,          % Outer margin
    top=25mm,            % Top margin
    bottom=25mm,         % Bottom margin
    marginparsep=5mm,    % Margin par separator
    marginparwidth=40mm, % Width of the margin paragraph
    twoside,             % Use different margins for odd and even pages
    bindingoffset=10mm   % Space for binding
]{geometry}
\usepackage{sidenotes}              
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\newcommand{\margincite}[1]{
  \marginnote{\textbf{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}}
}


\begin{document}


..has neither length, breadth, nor thickness\margincite{Euclid}...`; it is simply a precise location in space

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with my .bib having

```
  @book{Euclid,
  author    = "John Casey",
  title     = "The First Six Books of the Elements of Euclid",
  year      = "1885",
  publisher = "Dublin: Hodges, Figgis, and Co.; London: Longmans, Green, and Co.",
  address   = "Dublin"  
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want, please? `style=authoryear` is usually associated with author-year citations. So it is not quite clear to me what numerical citations would look like with that style and how that would differ from, say `style=numeric,`.

Comment: Maybe you want something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248726/35864? But see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470700/35864.